# NineOldAndroids library for Drag/Drop in android

Tags: android, api, drag-and-drop

i want to use Drag-and-Drop in my app. so I should use Nine Old Androids Library. I searchrd in GitHub and found out this solution:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids
I also download "Nine Old Androids.2.4.0.jar" from this site. and import this jar file to my app. but it doesn't work.
does"dependency" need? would you please help me how can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use gradle

in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.nineoldandroids', name: 'library', version: '2.4.0'
}
```