# Appium integration in Android Studio(Ubuntu)?

Tags: android-studio, appium

Hi anybody can provide me the steps for Appium(Automation tool) integration in Android studio for Ubuntu OS.

or Provide me any links(i gone through few blogs but most of them explained in Windows,Mac OS?).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is Download the Appium, junit Dependencies from Maven in your Android Studio Project and configure Android Studio to run Appium Java junit/TestNG test cases:

---

**You will require to download:**

> a. io.appium:java-client:3.1.0 or latest version
>
> b. org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit:4.11.0 Or Latest

Than Just write your test suit by providing Appium server capabilities and Setup/Teardown methods. Start Appium Server also give correct port number inside your code. Like:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

[How to import Maven Dependencies in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595287/how-to-import-maven-dependency-in-android-studio-intellij)

(I assume that Appium has already installed on your system) if not [Use This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374416/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu-for-android)

Comment: Thanks Darshan for your support...Let me try with those steps..If you don't mind can i have your mail id.

Comment: I have installed apppium server on my  ubuntu .But I am not able to understand how can i download that a and b (io.appium:java-client) and junit.com spring source in android studio