# Setting Facebook SDK does not work

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to set Facebook SDK using Maven,

```
    repositories {
    jcenter()       // IntelliJ main repo.
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+'
}
```

Now, the doubt is where should I keep the extracted Facebook SDK files?

Comment: what is your exact problem..

Comment: How to import Facebook SDK , properly? Tried other popular questions, cant seem to help me. After adding the dependencies, how do I import the SDK files?

Comment: See this thread accepted answer... possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595287/how-to-import-maven-dependency-in-android-studio-intellij